# Node, javascript, Read all files in a directory and return the lines that meet a specific condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

Problem: I have a directory that's filled with non-structured txt files containing thousands of logs.

My setup would be that i can somehow create a predefined text file that contains the matches for those logs, for example:

```
Time since start
Finished at
Total time
```

Then i need to loop and read every text file, and return the line that meets this criteria in a useable method, for example a large JSON set, or an object.

I've been playing around for some hours right now, but i just can't seem to make it work like it should.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you all

Comment: Sorry mate, on Stackoverflow, you are expected to provide your attempt and show us your code. If you're stuck at a particular point, we can try to help, but this is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

reading large files example, line by line with searching matches. Is this you are looking for?

`npm install linebyline --save`

```
const readline = require('linebyline')

// parsed matches lines
const matches = [
    'Time since start',
    'Finished at',
    'Total time'
]

// where matched lines will be stored
const matched = []

rl = readline('YOUR FILE PATH');

rl.on('line', function(line, lineCount) {

     console.log('line', lineCount, line)

        for(const match of matches) {
            if(line.includes(match)) {
                matched.push({
                    line: lineCount,
                    content: line
                }) 
            }
        }

})
.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e)
})
.on('end', function(e) {
    console.log(matched)
})
```

Comment: Yes, but every file in a directory.